# Change value in group according to first occurrence

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, group-by

I have this type of dataframe

```
    df <- data.frame(
        Hospital_ID= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
        COVID = c("YES", "NO", "", "NO", "", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES"))
    
      Hospital_ID COVID
1           1     YES
2           1     NO
3           1      
4           2     NO
5           2      
6           2     NO
7           3     NO
8           3     NO
9           3     YES
```

Column COVID is YES if there is some pactient with COVID and NO if there not and empty space if there was no tested patient

And I would like to change in another column value of COVID in group like this

```
      Hospital_ID COVID  COVID_IN_HOSPITAL
1           1     YES    YES
2           1     NO     YES
3           1            YES
4           2     NO     NO
5           2            NO
6           2     NO     NO
7           3     NO     YES
8           3     NO     YES
9           3     YES    YES
```

I try this code

```
df %>% 
 group_by(Hospital_ID) %>% 
 mutate(COVID_IN_HOSPITAL = ifelse(COVID = "YES", "YES", "NO") %>% 
 ungroup
```

But it was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `any`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Hospital_ID) %>% 
  mutate(COVID_IN_HOSPITAL = if_else(any(COVID == "YES"), "YES", "NO")) %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Hospital_ID COVID COVID_IN_HOSPITAL
        <dbl> <chr> <chr>            
1           1 "YES" YES              
2           1 "NO"  YES              
3           1 ""    YES              
4           2 "NO"  NO               
5           2 ""    NO               
6           2 "NO"  NO               
7           3 "NO"  YES              
8           3 "NO"  YES              
9           3 "YES" YES
```